# Why Google's ExoPlayer stop using Android low leve api MediaExtractor anymore?

Tags: android, exoplayer

Ive tried to understand how ExoPlayer works recently and studying their source code.

On the encoding / decoding part the I found that TrackRenderer wrap the low level api from MediaCodec class, and use it to decode/encode the data.

But for the Extracting part i only find one class -> FrameWorkSampleSource.java which use the low level api MediaExtractor, and its deprecated , even gone in ExoPlayer 2.0.

Is there any reason why exoplayer doesnt use this low level api to extract data from source? I thought this is the only way to extract media data in android device.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExoPlayer uses custom extractors written in Java, see [this package](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/library/core/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/extractor).

As for why:

> There are a few reasons:
>
> - MediaExtractor uses a threading model that's not well suited to
>     ExoPlayer.
> - It also doesn't provide as much control over buffering as
>     we'd like.
> - Implementation of the extractors under MediaExtractor
>     varies between versions of Android.
> - Extractors under MediaExtractor
>     lack some functionality that we're able to support in ExoPlayer
>     extractors.

See https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2580